# Excel VBA, How to copy cells from within a Column object

Tags: excel, vba, copy, copy-paste

I'm trying to use a 'For Each Column' loop to copy paste content from one sheet to another. 
I'm stuggling to reference the cells within the column object correctly. Or at least that's what I think the problem is.

Why is the line Sheets("Combo")... giving this error: Object doesn't support this property or method

```
Sub CRangeCopy()

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
ColNr = 1

For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns
    lastCellNr = c.Cells.Count
    c.Cells(2, lastCellNr).Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(2, ColNr).Paste ' Object doesn't support 
                                          ' this property or method
    ColNr = ColNr + 1
Next c

End Sub
```

Edit:

I've made the suggested changes and am now using Range, and the below code sometimes works in debug mode, but not when I run it as as whole? Any ideas why?

```
   Sub CopyToNewSheet()

   Sheets.Add.Name = "Combo"
   Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
        For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns
            Range(Cells(2, c.Column), Cells(4, c.Column)).Copy Sheets("Combo").Cells(2,  c.Column)
        Next c
   End Sub
```

Comment: what do you want to copy- whole columns? cells from some columns? some single cells from columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you want to copy range which starts in 2nd cell in each column within your UsedRange, and this range-to-copy should be as long as the last number of non-empty row in that column you should use this short code:

```
'... your code here
For Each c In ws.UsedRange.Columns
    lastCellNr = c.Cells.Count

    Range(Cells(2, c.Column), Cells(lastCellNr, c.Column)).Copy  Sheets("sheet2").Cells(2, ColNr)

    ColNr = ColNr + 1
Next c
'...rest of your code here
```

Short explanation: `Range.Copy` method allows to add `destination parameter` which need to refer to any other range. Syntax:

```
Range.Copy [DestinationRange]
```

Answer (score 0):

Paste is not a method of the range object.

That is why something as simple as:

```
Sub NoGood()
    Range("A1").Copy
    Range("A2").Paste
End Sub
```

will also fail.

Alternatives are to select the second sheet, select a cell on the second sheet and finally to paste to the second sheet.